# XMLDescendants to Object

Tags: c#, xml, casting, xelement

I am parsing XML to create an object. I am just unsure as to how to cast the var lotConfig into a LotCOnfig object.

I have tried :

```
var lotConfig =  (LotConfig) xml.Descendants("LOT_CONFIGURATON").Select(
```

and

```
return lotConfig as LotConfig
```

But None have worked so far.

```
 public LotConfig GetLotConfigData(FileInfo lotFile)
        {
            var xml = XElement.Load(lotFile.FullName);

            var lotConfig =  xml.Descendants("LOT_CONFIGURATON").Select(
                lot => new LotConfig
                {
                    LotNumber = (string) lot.Element("LOT_NUMBER").Value,
                    LotPartDescription = lot.Element("PART_DESCRIPTION").Value,
                    LotDate = lot.Element("LOT_DATE").Value,

                    ComponentList = lot.Descendants("ASSY_COMPONENT").Select(ac => new LotComponent
                       {
                           PartNumber = ac.Descendants("COMPONENT_PART_NUMBER").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                           ArtworkNumber = ac.Descendants("ARTWORK_NUMBER").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                           RefDesignator = ac.Descendants("REFERENCE_DESIGNATOR").FirstOrDefault().Value
                       }).ToList()
                });


            return lotConfig as LotConfig;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently `lotConfig` is of type `IEnumerable<LotConfig>`, you need to call `.FirstOrDefault()` at the end of your LINQ to make it return single `LotConfig` type :

```
var lotConfig =  xml.Descendants("LOT_CONFIGURATON")
                    .Select(
                        lot => new LotConfig
                        {
                            LotNumber = (string) lot.Element("LOT_NUMBER").Value,
                            LotPartDescription = lot.Element("PART_DESCRIPTION").Value,
                            LotDate = lot.Element("LOT_DATE").Value,

                            ComponentList = lot.Descendants("ASSY_COMPONENT").Select(ac => new LotComponent
                               {
                                   PartNumber = ac.Descendants("COMPONENT_PART_NUMBER").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                                   ArtworkNumber = ac.Descendants("ARTWORK_NUMBER").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                                   RefDesignator = ac.Descendants("REFERENCE_DESIGNATOR").FirstOrDefault().Value
                               }).ToList()
                        })
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```